# Split method is splitting into single String

Tags: java, string, split, java.util.scanner

I have a little problem:
I have a program that split a String by whitespace (only single ws), but when I assign that value to the String array, it has only one object inside. (I can print only '0' index).
Here is the code:

```
public void mainLoop() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        String parse = "#start";

        while (!parse.equals("#stop") || !parse.isEmpty()) {
            parse = sc.next();

            String[] line = parse.split("[ ]");
            System.out.println(line[0]);
        }
}
```

*The 'mainLoop' is called from instance by method 'main'.*

Comment: Try splitting on `\s`, like this: `parse.split("\\s")`

Comment: The `Pattern` should work. For which input `String` is this giving you an issue?

Comment: Can you please write the example of `input` and an expected `result`?

Comment: @SeniorJD Input should be: 'hello world!' And result should be: 0:'hello' 1:'world!' But my result is 0:'hello\nworld!' (The numbers are the indexes of objects in array).

Comment: @DrunkCoder your program never ends even if you enter `#stop` try `&&` operator instead of `||`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `Scanner#next` delimits input using a whitespace. You can use `nextLine` to read from the Scanner without using this delimiter pattern

```
parse = sc.nextLine();
```

The previous points mentioned in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25286755/split-method-is-splitting-into-single-string/25286787#comment39406665_25286755) are still valid

```
while (!parse.equals("#stop") && !parse.isEmpty()) {
    parse = sc.nextLine();

    String[] line = parse.split("\\s");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(line));
}
```

Comment: This delimiting of a space with [] appears to be intentional, though: "I have a program that split a String by whitespace (only single ws)"

Answer (score 0):

When you call `next` on scanner it returns next token from input. For instance if user will write text

```
foo bar
```

first call of `next` will return `"foo"` and next call of `next` will return `"bar"`.

Maybe consider using `nextLine` instead of `next` if you want to get string in form `"foo bar"` (entire line).

---

Also you don't have to place space in `[]` so instead of `split("[ ]")` you can use `split(" ")` or use character class `\s` which represents whitespaces `split("\\s")`.

---

Another problem you seem to have is

```
while( !condition1 || !condition2 )
```

If you wanted to say that loop should continue until either of conditions is fulfilled then you should write them in form

```
while( !(condition1 || condition2) )
```

or using [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws)

```
while( !condition1 && !condition2 )
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to split by a single whitespace, why don't you do it?

```
String[] line = parse.split(" ");
```